# Python generate thumbnail with transparancy and fixed width

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, sorl-thumbnail

So i am trying to generate thumbnails using Python/Django `sorl-thumbnail` library and i was asked to generate a 150x150 image, something like this (in case you can't see there are some transparent margins on top and on the bottom:

[image: Image to generate]

I tried to do:

```
get_thumbnail(
            original_image, '150x150', quality=99, format='PNG'
        )
```

Can i do that with `sorl-thumbnail`?? i mean add the transparencies on the top and on the bottom and keeping the full image size at 150x150? If not how can i achieve this with another python package?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about sorl-thumbnail but you can do it with Image. You basically need to create a transparent 150x150 image and put your thumbnail on top of it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from PIL import Image

margin=20
X=150
Y=150
in_path="flower.jpg"
out_path="thumbnail.png"

#creates a transparent background, RGBA mode, and size 150 by 150.
background = Image.new('RGBA', (X,Y))


# opening an image and converting to RGBA:
img = Image.open(in_path).convert('RGBA')

# Resizing the image

img = img.resize((X, Y-margin*2), Image.ANTIALIAS)

# Putting thumbnail on background

background.paste(img, (0, margin), img)
background.save(out_path)
```

The output with transparent stripes at the top and bottom:

[image]